# R: cannot fully capture all arguments using deparse and substitute when function call is 3 dots

Tags: r

I am trying to capture all arguments of a function call so deparse and substitute are used. It has worked well until I want to extend the usage of the function using 3 dots as arguments; turns out only the first argument is captured. A simplified version of the function is shown below.

```
func_3dot <- function(...){
  tmp <- deparse(substitute(...))
  print(tmp)
}
```

For the example below [1] "mod_1" "mod_2" are expected. Is there any way I could still capture all input arguments without changing the above function much? Thanks!!

```
mod_1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
mod_2 <- update(mod_1, . ~ . + hp)

> func_3dot(mod_1, mod_2)
[1] "mod_1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list(...)` instead of just `...`, and deparse the entries separately.  For example,

```
func_3dot <- function(...){
  tmp <- substitute(list(...))
  sapply(tmp, deparse)[-1]
}
```

The `[-1]` removes the call to `list` from the deparsed results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match.call`:

```
func_3dot <- function(...){
  tmp <- vapply(as.list((match.call()[-1])), deparse, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
  print(tmp)
}

func_3dot(mod_1, mod_2)
#[1] "mod_1" "mod_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `purrr` and `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
func_3dot <- function(...){
    unname(map_chr(quos(...), quo_name))
  }

func_3dot(mod_1, mod_2)
#[1] "mod_1" "mod_2"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
func_3dot <- function(...){
   sapply(as.list(substitute(...())), deparse)
 }

func_3dot(mod_1, mod_2)
#[1] "mod_1" "mod_2"
```

Comment: Thanks!!! somehow I cannot install rlang without devtools but it works!